# What is the meaning of the square brackets in theorem 8.6.30 (Introduction to Graph Theory) book?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, notation, proof-explanation

In the book (Introduction to Graph Theory) by Douglas West , what is the meaning of the square brackets in $|[ S , \overline{S} ]|$ ?

[image: WHAT NOTATION]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For $A,B\subseteq V(G)=V$, $[A,B]$ is the set of edges in the graph $G$ joining $A$ and $B$.  Then you take the cardinality of this set to get $\lvert [A,B]\rvert$.  Apply this to the case $A=S$ and $B=\bar{S}=V-S$.

Answer (score 2):

That text book has the Answer on Page 152 :

**"Given $S , T \subset V(G)$ , we write $[S , T]$ for the Set of Edges having one End-Point in $S$ and the other in $T$.

An Edge Cut is an Edge Set of the form $[S , \overline{S}]$ , where $S$ is a Non-Empty Proper Sub-Set of $V(G)$ and $\overline{S}$ denotes $V(G) - S$."**

Concisely , the Author later states that **"It is the set of edges joining a vertex in $S$ to a vertex not in $S$"** , which is very Intuitive.

More-over , it is standard convention / notation to use $|A|$ to indicate Size of Set $A$.

Hence , $|[S , \overline{S}]|$ indicates **"the Size of the Edge Cut"** , while that theorem is giving a lower Bound on this Size.

Here is that Page with more Detail :

[image: EDGE CUT]